# Panel leaving white space when Scrollbar appears

Tags: extjs

I'm building an application using Ext.js, and I built a grid panel, and I'm loading data every 14 seconds. When the scrollbar appears on the panel, it appears an white space that I'm trying to remove but I don't know how, I already tried to overwrite the ID that contains the timeline and change the color, but it didn't work because Ext.js generated the CSS code again and every changes disappeared.

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEtZJ.png)
[image]

Is it possible to hide this white space?

My code:

```js
Ext.define('ES.view.Layout.Menu.Menu', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.timelineBar',
  controller: 'menu',
  viewModel: 'menu',
  autoScroll: true,

  title: 'Timeline',
  bodyStyle: 'background: #2b5876;',
  store: {
    type: 'timeline'
  },
  columns: {
    border: false,

    defaults: {
      hoverCls: ''
    },

    items: [{
        text: locale.time,
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'time',
        align: 'center',
        height: 60
      },
      {
        text: locale.address,
        dataIndex: 'address',
        flex: 1,
        align: 'center',
        height: 60

        listeners: {

          click: 'onItemClick'

        },
      },
      {
        text: locale.dir,
        dataIndex: 'dir',
        flex: 1,
        align: 'right',
        height: 60

      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a example fiddle for this recreating the issue?

Comment: its your grid or panel that have that white place??

Comment: Sorry, the grid is leaving this white space when I drag the grid headers the space disappears